# Count how many times, part of a given sequence is repeated in the SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my form I have a Dynamic Array Label with 15 indexes where every day there is a new random draw of 15 numbers between 1 to 25 and saved in the SQL Server database.

I need to compare each new draw generated in the array with the database records and know, how many records in the database appear with 11 numbers Equal to the sequence generated from the array, how many records appear with 12 numbers Equal to the generated array, how many records appear with 13 numbers I like the generated array, how many records appear with 14 numbers like the generated array, how many records appear with the 15 numbers like the generated array, records with less than 11 numbers like the generated array do not need to be shown.

I have approximately 2500 records saved in the database, called via query by class controller, I need to show the results of the same numbers in five label.Text, one for each result from 11 to 15, I tried to make a query with the Count instruction () Group By, but I did not reach a satisfactory result.

I accept any type of indication, suggestion or examples, I am leaving an image as an example of how my table is, as well as this one in the table I am bringing to a DataGridView via query, in advance I apologize if my question is not well prepared, and I appreciate any response.

[image]

I have only one table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Result](
[Concurso] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_01] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_02] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_03] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_04] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_05] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_06] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_07] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_08] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_09] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_10] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_11] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_12] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_13] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_14] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[_15] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,

 cmd.CommandText = "insert into Result(Contest,_01,_02,_03,_04,_05,_06,_07,_08,_09,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15)" +
   " Values(@Contest,@_01,@_02,@_03,@_04,@_05,@_06,@_07,@_08,@_09,@_10,@_11,@_12,@_13,@_14,@_15)";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contest", number.Contest);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_01", number.n_01.ToString("D2"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_02", number.n_02.ToString("D2"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_03", number.n_03.ToString("D2"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_04", number.n_04.ToString("D2"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_05", number.n_05.ToString("D2"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_06", number.n_06.ToString("D2"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_07", number.n_07.ToString("D2"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_08", number.n_08.ToString("D2"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_09", number.n_09.ToString("D2"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_10", number.n_10.ToString("D2"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_11", number.n_11.ToString("D2"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_12", number.n_12.ToString("D2"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_13", number.n_13.ToString("D2"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_14", number.n_14.ToString("D2"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_15", number.n_15.ToString("D2"));
```

Comment: What do the annotations in red - like `12=0` - represent exactly?  It’s not clear what you’re trying to do here.

Comment: 11 =2, 12 =0 13 =1, are the repetitions, comparing the Database with the result of the label, there are 2 records in the database with 11 numbers equal to the sequence of the label and there are zero records in the database with 12 numbers equal to the sequence of the label and there is 1 record in the Database with 13 numbers equal to the sequence of the label.

Comment: Edit you question and tell us 1) How comparing the values of the _create result_ sequence and the underlined record should mean `13=1` while only the first `8` values are equals. 2) Do you have the db records loaded in a data container like `DataTable`, `List<T>`? Or you need to execute a query against the database? 3) Some relevant code might help us to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: dr.null the image shows some results to get an idea of how the Database is being formed, the results in red would be what goes in the Lebel.Text, I thought of querying the Database directly, but I also have these results in a.txt file, I don't know which one would have a better result.

Comment: Add the query you tried, it might help clarify your question.

Comment: And, assuming you are interested in a SQL query answer, show us the table structure of both tables with sample data, ideally as DDL+DML so we can copy and paste to play with it.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpivot the array and the result and then do a join and count the matching rows.

It will be very much better if you can provide the DDL & DML.

Without it, assuming your array table is like

```
create table the_array
(
    id  int,
    _01 char(2),
    _02 char(2),
    _03 char(2),
    . . .
)
```

Assuming your result `02,03,04` etc are in a similar structure as your array

```
create table #result
(
    _01 char(2),
    _02 char(2),
    _03 char(2),
    . . .
)
```

Unpivot both and perform an `INNER JOIN` to count the number of matches.

```
with 
result as
(
  select val
  from   #result
         cross apply
         (
             values
             (_01), (_02), (_03), (_04), (_05)
         ) v (val)
),
arr as
(
  select id, val
  from   the_array
         cross apply
         (
             values
             (_01), (_02), (_03), (_04), (_05), . . .
         ) v (val)  
)
select s.id, count(*) as TheCount
from   result r
       inner join arr a on r.val = a.val
group by s.id
```

With the query you are almost there to get the required `13 = 1`, `12 = 0` etc